# Lumen - Postgresql setup - Composer

Tags: php, laravel-5, docker-compose, lumen

really strugling on this one, it's not the first I try to set this up but I really can't see why it's not working.

So this is my app.docker file:

```
FROM php:7-fpm
# Install modules
RUN buildDeps="libpq-dev libzip-dev libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev " && apt-get update && apt-get install -y $buildDeps --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql gd

WORKDIR /var/www

COPY . /var/www

RUN chown www-data:www-data -R ./storage

RUN ln -s /storage/app/public /public
```

Pretty simple. Next comes the output of phpinfo()

[image]

I understand that the pgsql driver is now installed, however, when running php artisan migrate I still get

[image]

This is my config/database.php file.

```
return [
    'default' => 'postgres',
    'migrations' => 'migrations',
    'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'port'      => env('DB_PORT'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
        'mysql_postal_code' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE_POSTAL_CODE'),
            'port'      => env('DB_PORT'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
        'postgres' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_PG_HOST', 'database_p'),
            'database' => env('DB_PG_DATABASE', 'dockerApp'), // This seems to be ignored
            'port'     => env('DB_PG_PGSQL_PORT', 5432),
            'username' => env('DB_PG_USERNAME', 'postgres'),
            'password' => env('DB_PG_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public'
        ]
    ],
    'redis' => [
        'cluster' => false,
        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],
    ],
];
```

What can I be missing?

Comment: Have you run `php artisan config:cache`?

Comment: Currently using Lumen so no config:cache is available for me

Comment: Right, are you sure PostgreSQL support is enabled in command line? Run `php -m` to see enabled modules. I have `pdo_pgsql` and  `pgsql` listed

Answer (score 0):

**solution**: you need to run the following commands on your terminal;

php -version : to get your exact PHP version for example in my case i get

```
mykmyk@skynet:/var/www/practicefolder/BooksCharactersAPI$ php -version
PHP 8.0.18 (cli) (built: Apr 21 2022 10:14:36) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.18, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.18, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
mykmyk@skynet:/var/www/practicefolder/BooksCharactersAPI$
```

as shown above my php-version is 8.0.18
then use this "php version number" in the below command , still on your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-pgsql
```

Notice i plugged in my exact PHP version 8.0.18 , in the command php8.0-pgsql leaving out the last digit.
so in your case yours will be "sudo apt-get install phpx.x-pgsql", x.x designating your PHP version number.

After this try out the migrate command again.